# Gmail notification sound only for new mail

Tags: notifications, gmail

I am using the Google Gmail app, which I've configured to play a notification sound for new mail.

However, it actually plays the notification sound when there is any change at all to the account while I use it on the computer -- reading messages, deleting messages, etc -- in addition to when new mail actually arrives.

It's driving me crazy! How can I configure this so it only makes a sound when a new message arrives in my inbox?

Comment: What version of the app are you using?  I have v2.3.4.1 and it doesn't do this.

Comment: What device and carrier do you have? I don't see (hear) this behavior at all.

Comment: Further, what are your Notification settings in the Gmail app?

Comment: I get the issue if I mark anything as unread or move an unread archived item back into the inbox (i.e. the notification happens if the number of unread items in the inbox increases)

Comment: I think you want to turn on the "Notify once" setting.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>You haven't specified the Android OS version nor the Gmail app version, but since the settings are pretty much straightforward, I'll leave here an overview covering the basics for all available versions.</sup>

## Summary

Three things might be happening:

- You are receiving notifications for each email that arrives;
- You have the "notify once" active and are receiving notifications for the email that arrived, but also for a label you've setup to notify;
- You are receiving notifications from the Gmail app, and from another app where you've also configured the same account.

Below is a summary for the Gmail app settings by version. Try and adjust them to fit your needs.

If you continue to experience the same issue, you're probably facing a bug and the best option is to [report it](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/request.py?contact_type=contact_policy).

---

## Android 4.0.x (Ice cream sandwich)

To change Gmail settings, touch "Menu" > "Settings" from any Gmail screen.

Under "Account settings", you will find:

- Email notifications:

  > When checked, you receive a notification when you have new email.
- Ringtone:

  > Available when "Email notifications" is selected.
  >
  > Touch to change any of three settings: The ringtone and vibrate settings for notifications, and an option to notify only the first time you have new email since you last read your messages, rather than each time a new message arrives.

[Official Gmail app support page by Google for this Android version.](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1687263&topic=1687320&ctx=topic)

## Android 3.0.x (Honeycomb)

To change Gmail settings, touch the Menu button at the top-right of the Application bar and touch Settings.

Under "Account settings", you will find:

- Email notifications

  > When checked, you receive a notification when you have new email.
- Notify once

  > Check to receive a notification from Gmail only the first time you have new email since you last read your messages, rather than each time a new message arrives.

[Official Gmail app support page by Google for this Android version.](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168979&topic=1133932&ctx=topic)

## Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread)

To access the Gmail app's Account settings menu:

1. Open Gmail.
2. Press Menu.
3. Select More > Settings > Select account

Under "Notification settings", you will find:

- Email notifications

  > When checked, you'll receive a notification when you have new email.
- Labels to notify

  > Manage your notification preferences by label. You can only manage notification settings by label for [labels that are synced](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168499).

  You can enable notifications for specific labels, each means additional notifications when emails arrive:

  > When you enable sync for a particular label, you can also change your notification preferences so that you're notified when you receive new mail for that label.

  1. Press Menu and touch More > Settings. Select the Gmail account whose settings you'd like to modify.
  2. Touch Labels to notify.
  3. Select a labels to change the notification preferences. You can modify the following settings:

     - Email notifications
     - Ringtone
     - Vibrate
     - Notify once

     Only labels that have been set to sync will appear in the notifications menu.

[Official Gmail app support page by Google for this Android version.](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1350790&topic=1407457&ctx=topic)

Comment: Good answer but I cant find that screen on 4.0.4. In the gmail app use the left button to get to settings and I have general settings which doesnt have anything about notification or ringtone.