# Why does Android GMail app pop an icon for new mail when I delete a message in web GMail?

Tags: notifications, gmail, sync

I have my GMail Android app set to notify on new messages.

However, it ALSO pops up notifications when I simply delete an existing (new or read) message from the web-based gmail.com

**Is there an explanation of why this happens and how to stop it?**

I saw a related question on A.SE -  [Gmail notification sound only for new mail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8199/gmail-notification-sound-only-for-new-mail) - but it was for notifications when marking messages as unread or moving the messages into Inbox.

Also, it wasn't answered and the only helpful comment wasn't something I can use (Turn on "Notify Once" setting) since this would ALSO stop per-new-message individual notifications which I need to have.

UPDATE: If it matters: Droid X, rooted stock Froyo 2.2. Gmail - latest version but this behavior was the same for the last year, with all versions of the app (likely since day 1, I just didn't use gmail on the web back then too frequently).

Comment: Which phone, Android OS version and GMail app version are you using?

Comment: @Chahk - updated with deatils.

Comment: I've seen similar behavior (a notification after reading/deleting previously unread messages in the web interface). My first guess is that the Gmail app only knows that the number of unread messages has changed - it doesn't know *how* it has changed.

Comment: That's extra annoying since the standard mail app has no problem like that with my Yahoo account